# Prove series is convergent based on the convergence of the sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I need to prove:

> If $\sum(a_n + b_n)$ is convergent and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0}$ then the series
> $$ a_1 + b_1 + a_2 + b_2 + \cdots $$
> is convergent.

I was trying to use Cauchy's convergence test but I am feeling like I am missing something and I will be happy if someone can confirm my proof.

*Proof:* We need to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a natural number $N$ such that:

$$|a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}+b_{n+p} +a_{n+p+1}|<\varepsilon $$

holds for all $n > N$ and all $p \ge 1$. That's because we know the series $\sum(a_n + b_n)$ is convergent and therefore by Cauchy's convergence test for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a natural number $N$ such that:

$$|a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}+b_{n+p}|<\varepsilon $$

holds for all $n > N$ and all $p \geq 1$.

From what we have just mentioned we can deduce that for every $\varepsilon/2 > 0$ there is a natural number $N_1$ such that:

$$|a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}+b_{n+p}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

holds for all $n > N_1$ and all $p \geq 1$.

Moreover from the fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, we can deduce that for every $\varepsilon/2 > 0$ there is a natural number $N_2$ such that:

$$|a_n| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \qquad\text{for all } n > N_2.$$

Let us define $N_3 = \max\{ N_1, N_2 \} $, then for all $n > N_3$ and for all $p \geq 1$:

\begin{align*}
&|a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}+b_{n+p} +a_{n+p+1}| \\
&\leq |a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}+\cdots +a_{n+p}+b_{n+p}| + |a_{n+p+1}| \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
= \varepsilon
\end{align*}

I will be grateful for any comments for my proof, many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Cauchy criterion here.

Let

$$
c_n = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        a_{(n+1)/2} & \mbox{if } n  \text{ is odd} \\
        b_{n/2} & \mbox{if } n \text{ is even}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

and let
$$C_n = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k$$

The question is to prove that $(C_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Let $\displaystyle{S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k + b_k)}$. By assumption, the sequence $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ converges to a limit $L$.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, one has
$$C_{2n} = S_n$$
$$C_{2n+1} = S_n + a_{n+1}$$

Becasue $a_n \longrightarrow 0$, then both the subsequences $(C_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(C_{2n+1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to the same limit ($L$), which implies directly that
$$\boxed{(C_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ converges.}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I am just wondering if I didn't make any mistakes on my proof, do you see anything wrong?

Comment: @Yarin Your proof seems correct, but it is quite strange to use Cauchy criterion here, since the statement does not rely at all on the completeness on the space.

Comment: My main issue for some reason was the difficulty to obtain a formula that will describe the desired sequence this is why I did it like that, but your proof made it clearer for me.
Thank you !

Comment: @Yarin You are welcome !